# How to deal with overestimation of small values and underestimation of high values in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I'm running `XGBoost` to predict prices on a `cars dataset`, I was wondering what alternatives are there for this kind of problem where smaller values are overestimated and higher prices underestimated.

I tried applying `log` to prices since it has a skewed to the right distribution, but still having this undesirable effect.

Also, as a bonus question, log(price) improved the prediction score, the mean relative error or MRE calculated as mean(ABS(RD)) by 2 percent, if anyone has the intuition onto why this could have happened that would be great.

In the image below `RD` is the `relative difference` between predictions and the actual values, and the `price bucket` is a bucketized variable where the number indicates the `price low interval bound over 1000`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think its necessarily related to the type of algorithm performing the regression(XGBoost here) - but to inherent nature of regression algorithms.
Many loss function are aimed to reduce distance between $y$ and $\hat{y}$.
That can lead to model predictions distribution being tighter around $y$'s mean.

Couple of things I would check to verify this:
1) Compare distribution of real $y$ and predicted $\hat{y}$.
2) Verify this error pattern on others regression model.

Things I would try to improve results:
1) over sample low/high y values in training set.
2) Adjust loss function so errors on low/high y values will have more weight.
3) Look for features that emphasize low/high y values and engineer them better.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using multiple XgBoost models instead of 1 and take an average (or weighted average) of their predictions.