Why is my random forest regressor more likely to under-predict when making larger predictions?
I've recently built my first regression model, using scikit-learn's random forest regressor. The predictions are rounded into one of 12 segments; these begin at £15 and progress in £5 increments up to £70.
For my purposes, predictions which are too high are preferred to predictions which are too low.
The model performs reasonably well in terms of accuracy. However, whether it predicts lower or higher than what happens in the real world varies significantly depending on how high the prediction is. This can be seen on the chart below, which shows the proportion of the predictions in each segment which are lower or higher than real world behaviour.
Does anyone know why this might be happening please, and how I can best flatten the slope, so to speak?
I can potentially increase the predictions for some of the people in the higher segments (effectively bumping them up a segment or two), but this feels a bit clumsy. I tried training a linear regression model on the predictions & target variable from the test dataset, then using its slope and intercept in the linear regression formula to calibrate the model's predictions to be more accurate, but this did not seem to do much.
Any advice or ideas are much appreciated!


I think this is probably just "regression to the mean"; see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603435/232706 and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/45563/55122
